# twitter bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make an accordion in my website similar to that seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gqe7g/242/). However, whenever I click on the place to accordion down, it does not drop but instead links me to my_url#collapseOne (or two or three depending on which one I click on). And, when I load the webpage, menu 1 is already dropped (not desirable) and the other two look correct.

Any ideas on how to properly implement the accordion effect?

Comment: Show us your mark up, we can't advise on where you're going wrong without your markup

Comment: You could start by following the instructions on the [doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse), and don't forget to check that jQuery and the plugin file(s) are included

Comment: The markup I kinked to is the one I pasted into my code. My code is fairly long though and I wasn't sure what other parts were relevant. I think I'm most confused about why it links to url +'#collapseNumber' when clicked and scrolls the page down to that place. The only reason I could think that it would do that was because earlier in the code, I have a top menu where you can click and it links down to hash tagged hrefs. [Slightly updated markup](http://jsfiddle.net/gqe7g/244/), not sure if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

So there are two things you need to do

1. When the document is ready, you need to initialise your accordions. That means you will go through all of the accordion containers and initialise them to closed.
2. You will be attaching click event handlers to links that open/close the accordion. To prevent the browser following those link, you should return false from those event handlers, which stops the event from bubbling up any further. This will stop the browser from following the link.

Comment: You don't need to do that since the plugin does it. You do need to initialize the accordions, but you can activate all of them, or even use the markup `data-toggle="collapse"` so that you don't need any JavaScript : [doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse).

Comment: It was my assumption that the OP was trying to make a custom accordion because they do just work. The example included does everything that was asked for as well. Perhaps it would be nice to see some source code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about web design. I took the markup I posted and placed that in my code, and the results were as described. I wasn't sure what else would be useful in a markup. I also found it odd that it redirects to the url with '#collapseNumber' appended. Earlier in my code I have a menu at the top which links to places later down in the page that are hash tagged hrefs.

Answer (score 1):

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse.  If you customized your bootstrap install make sure you have the required files.  If you are using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem with the asset pipeline you should be good to just drop that code in and see it work.

Comment: I do have the required files. [This](http://i.imgur.com/1jwGB.png) is what it looks like when I drag and drop the html that is written on the site you linked me to. Also clicking on them causes the page to link to them. ie, it goes to url + '#collapseNumber'.